# Find fit with custom equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find a fit with a custom equation, but I keep getting errors and don't know why. The custom equation is really big. I'm using what I found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fittype.html?s_tid=doc_ta#btpaend-8).

This is the code (sorry about the length of the custom equation):

```
myfittype = fittype('a + (b*2*y) + (c*2*x+dsqrt(6)(2*xy)) + (esqrt(3)*(2*x^2+2*y^2-1)) + (fsqrt(6)(x^2-y^2)) + (gsqrt(8)(3*x^2*y-y^3)) + (hsqrt(8)(3*x^2*y+3*y^3-2*y)) + (ipsqrt(8)(x^3+3*x*y^2-2*x)) + (jpsqrt(8)(x^3-3*xy^2)) + (ksqrt(10)*(4*x^3*y-4*xy^3)+lsqrt(10)*(8*x^3*y+8*x*y^3-6*xy)) + (msqrt(5)*(6*x^4+12*x^2*y^2+6*y^4-6*x^2-6*y^2+1)) + (nsqrt(10)(4*x^4+4*x^2*y^2-3*x^2-4*x^2*y^2-4*y^4+3*y^2)) + (osqrt(10)(x^4-6*x^2*y^2+y^4)) + (psqrt(12)(5*x^4*y-10*x^2*y^3+y^5)) + (qsqrt(12)(15*x^4*y-12*x^2*y-5*y^5+4*y^3+10*x^2*y^3)) + (rsqrt(12)(10*x^4*y+20*x^2*y^3+10*y^5-12*x^2*y-12*y^3+3*y)) + (ssqrt(12)(10*x^5+20*x^3*y^2+10*x*y^4-12*x^3-12*x*y^2+3*x)) + (tsqrt(12)(5*x^5-10*x^3*y^2-4*x^3-15*x*y^4+12*xy^2)) + (usqrt(12)*(x^5-10*x^3*y^2+5*x*y^4))',... 'independent',{'x'},'dependent',{'y'},...
'coefficients',{'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','ip','jp','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u'})
```

Here is the code formatted with line breaks (`...`) so that you can read it:

```
myfittype = fittype('a + (b*2*y) + (c*2*x+d*sqrt(6)*(2*x*y)) + ...
         (e*sqrt(3)*(2*x^2+2*y^2-1)) + (f*sqrt(6)*(x^2-y^2)) + ...
         (g*sqrt(8)*(3*x^2*y-y^3)) + (h*sqrt(8)*(3*x^2*y+3*y^3-2*y)) + ...
         (ip*sqrt(8)*(x^3+3*x*y^2-2*x)) + (jp*sqrt(8)*(x^3-3*x*y^2)) + ...
         (k*sqrt(10)*(4*x^3*y-4*x*y^3)+l*sqrt(10)*(8*x^3*y+8*x*y^3-6*x*y)) + ...
         (m*sqrt(5)*(6*x^4+12*x^2*y^2+6*y^4-6*x^2-6*y^2+1)) + ...
         (n*sqrt(10)*(4*x^4+4*x^2*y^2-3*x^2-4*x^2*y^2-4*y^4+3*y^2)) + ...
         (o*sqrt(10)*(x^4-6*x^2*y^2+y^4)) + (p*sqrt(12)*(5*x^4*y-10*x^2*y^3+y^5)) + ...
         (q*sqrt(12)*(15*x^4*y-12*x^2*y-5*y^5+4*y^3+10*x^2*y^3)) + ...
         (r*sqrt(12)*(10*x^4*y+20*x^2*y^3+10*y^5-12*x^2*y-12*y^3+3*y)) + ...
         (s*sqrt(12)*(10*x^5+20*x^3*y^2+10*x*y^4-12*x^3-12*x*y^2+3*x)) + ...
         (t*sqrt(12)*(5*x^5-10*x^3*y^2-4*x^3-15*x*y^4+12*x*y^2)) + ...
         (u*sqrt(12)*(x^5-10*x^3*y^2+5*x*y^4))', ...
         'independent',{'x'},'dependent',{'y'}, ...    
         'coefficients', ...   
         {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','ip','jp','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u'})
```

The error says this expression is not a valid matlab expression

Hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: If you format your code correctly, the `*` will not disappear. Certainly you just have a typo in your equation which you need to fix.

Comment: @Jonathon the problem is that i defined this exact equation as an anonymous function and no error

Comment: Are the `...` supposed to be there?

Comment: i can take them off but then i'll have to write the big thing in one line, this way is easier to see

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I added most of the `...` to make the code readable. They are valid MATLAB syntax for line continuation and don't affect the question. I have, however, also just added back the original code for completeness since this is a syntax error question.

Comment: @CecíliaCoelho Does your real code have `'coefficients', {'a',` on a new line without a `...` at the end of the previous line? If so then that's a syntax issue.

Comment: @wolfie nope it has the ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run your code :

The problem  of your code is that

**Coefficient d does not appear in the equation expression.**